# suggestion to reduce jQuery code for hide show on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this, I try to do hide and show the div's.

It's working well but I want to reduce this code because it looks like same on click function

```
 $(document).ready(function() {        
        $(".product_pro").show();
        $(".product_retail").hide();
        $(".product_food").hide();
        $(".product_xclusive").hide();
        $(".retail-pro").addClass('pro-active');
    
        $(".retail-pro").click(function() {
            $(".product_retail").show();
            $(".product_pro").hide();
            $(".food-pro").removeClass('pro-active');
            $(".xclusive-pro").removeClass('pro-active');
            $(".retail-pro").addClass('pro-active');
            $(".product_food").hide();
            $(".product_xclusive").hide();
        });
        $(".food-pro").click(function() {
            $(".product_retail").hide();
            $(".product_food").show();
            $(".product_pro").hide();
            $(".food-pro").addClass('pro-active');
            $(".retail-pro").removeClass('pro-active');
            $(".xclusive-pro").removeClass('pro-active');
            $(".product_xclusive").hide();
        });
       
    
    });
```

Comment: So list multiple selectors for elements for which you want to do the same thing in _one_ `$(…)` then …?

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: `So list multiple selectors for elements for which you want to do the same thing in one $(…) then …?` and also change your code to use common classes where the behaviours are the same, instead of targeting each element individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
        $(".product_pro").show();
        $(".product_retail").hide();
        $(".product_food").hide();
        $(".product_xclusive").hide();
        $(".retail-pro").addClass('pro-active');
        
        $(".retail-pro").click(function() {  
            hideOrDisplayElements(1);
        });
        $(".food-pro").click(function() {
            hideOrDisplayElements(0);
        });
    });

function hideOrDisplayElements(blnIsRetailProClicked){
  $(".product_retail, .product_food")[blnIsRetailProClicked ? 'show' : 'hide']();
  $(".food-pro, .retail-pro")[blnIsRetailProClicked ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass']('pro-active');
  $(".xclusive-pro").removeClass('pro-active');
  $(".product_xclusive .product_pro").hide();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i tried with your code but it nothing happend to me..

Comment: Can you please provide the html as well for me to look into this further?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
  $(".product_pro").show();
  $(".product_retail, .product_food, .product_xclusive").hide();
  $(".retail-pro").addClass('pro-active');

  $(".retail-pro").click(function() {
    $(".product_retail").show();
    $(".food-pro, .xclusive-pro").removeClass('pro-active')
    $(".retail-pro").addClass('pro-active');
    $(".product_food, .product_xclusive, .product_pro").hide();
  });
  
  $(".food-pro").click(function() {
    $(".product_retail, .product_pro, .product_xclusive").hide();
    $(".product_food").show();
    $(".food-pro").addClass('pro-active');
    $(".retail-pro, .xclusive-pro").removeClass('pro-active');
  });
});
```

But I'd recommend to put a common class in the elements you want hidden or visible in the different states, change the class of the container by state (not each element), and manage everything with css.

Much simpler and cleaner.

Comment: can we do much more simpler with your code. @alotroico